# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0:

Tags: android, android-appcompat, resolve

Error:

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0:

How do I solve this error?

Config:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.ummat.qmduain"
            minSdkVersion 11
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0'
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        productFlavors {
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile files('libs/hvjavacal.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
        compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to compile version 22, but your compile SDK version is 23.

Solution:

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a mismatch in your compile `sdkVersion` and support library version. You should use `23.0.0` or a newer version in 23.
On a side note, you are on a very old library versions. I would recommend bump up to 27 unless you have some other requirement.